# Whitescreen in XAMPP and PHPMYADMIN at Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed XAMPP 1.8.1 recently and totally fine in Mozila Firefox 16.0.2 . but it show only whitescreen when i tried to call ,  localhost/phpmyadmin and localhost/xampp 
at Chrome ( 17.0.963.2) . but i doubted that because of cache and history then  i wiped out all of  browser 's history and cache and others . but it still exist as whitescreen .  but when i tried to edit xampp/index.php as

```
<?php echo "something"; ?>
```

it will show "something" via whitescreen at both browsers .  do you have any idea to fix it ?? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installed Chrome from the beginning and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This occured to me when I discovered there were zero bytes available on my C: drive.